# how to lock scrolling on a <div> behind a <div>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a page that appends a div to the body of a html. However the issue now is that I have two scrolls going on (one on the new overlaying div and the other one behind it), here's the structure of the page approximately, how do I make it such that only this new appended div is the one that can be scrolled, not behind it.

Here's the structure approxiamtely:

```
<div class="right col clearfix>
<div class="modal container in">
</div>
</div>
```

basically I only wanted the modal container in to be the one that scrolls and nothing else.

Comment: unbind the scroll event to that div which you want not to scroll .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HTML**

```
<div class="right col clearfix>
    <div class="modal container in"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.right col clearfix {
    overflow: hidden;
}
.modal container in {
    width: //your width;
    height: //yourheight;
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

Comment: I have the same problem. I have a table and an external JSP in the main div(right col clearfix). When I use overflow:hidden in the table, overflown columns are hidden. I see only a blank space.

Comment: <div id="table">
    <jsp:include page="searchgroup.jsp"></jsp:include>
    <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
   <div id="grid1" jsid="grid1" dojoType="dojox.grid.EnhancedGrid" query="{ name: '*' }"
      data-dojo-props="plugins:{ pagination:{pageSizes: ['10', '25', '50', '100'],
                            description: true, sizeSwitch: true, pageStepper: true, gotoButton: true, position: 'bottom', maxPageStep: 7}}, rowsPerPage:10"></div>
This is my code. Can you provide me with the scroll option for the main div(#table)?

Comment: I want the div(#table) with scroll bar.

Comment: div #table { width://your width; height: //your height; overflow://scroll; }

Comment: Only half of the columns of #grid1 are visible even after scroll

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37145/discussion-between-anusha-honey-and-upvote-markanswer)